# Ubuntu installation to USB stick removed windows MBR

Tags: usb, windows, mbr

Got a Windows 8.1 Lenovo laptop. Installed Ubuntu 14.04 to an USB Stick.

Can boot into this Ubuntu on a stick. But not into Windows. Want to restore Windows boot. I can still boot into Windows if I go into Bios on booting and select the Windows SSD.

a) how I installed: copied ubuntu install iso to an usb stick A. From this stick did full installation to another stick B. Can boot into B but no longer into Windows. If I select Windows partition from Grub, system hangs.

b) tried to restore with Windows 8.1 boot media on a stick (http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media). Can boot from the stick, but it refuses to restore MBR.

What can I do to restore MBR?

Answer (score 0):

You got 2 options depending on wether you want to install Ubuntu with Dual-booting, or just reverting to the normal Windows boot.

Restoring normal windows MBR, see this link: https://neosmart.net/wiki/fix-mbr/
Go allmost to the bottom where Windows 8.1 method is found, follow these steps.

Dual-booting with Ubuntu. From inside Windows re-size your windows partition, to make space for Ubuntu, do not format the new unused space, shut windows down!
Plug in your Ubuntu Live Iso, boot this and let it start up, choose to install Ubuntu in the empty space, when asked where to place the Grub loader select /dev/sda.
Ubuntu then finds your Windows and set up the boot-menu.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, I will try 1.

Is there no chance to put a full Ubuntu on a stick and have it boot without modifying the hard discs at all? My bios could boot from an arbitrary partition.